# missing value '--' while reading netCDF file

Tags: python, pandas, missing-data, netcdf4

while reading a NetCDF file, I store my water column data into a dataframe to read it again. In the dataframe I come up with missing values `--` which might also be known as "masked" values. I tried replacing them using `filedata.replace('--','nan')` but it replaces even the floats and I get an entire dataframe with nan. Also pd.dropna() didn't work. 
What would be the good way to either avoide these values during reading the netcdf, or replace them in the dataframe with nans without affecting the float numbers? Here is a sample part of my dataframe:

```
so_1    so_2    so_3
--  --  --
--  --  --
--  --  --
--  --  --
31.99   32.09   32.22
--  --  --
--  --  --
--  --  --
--  --  --
32.08   32.15   32.18
32.0871 32.11   32.17
--  --  --
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You could use the numpy NaN (you will have to import numpy as np)

```
    df.replace('--', np.nan)
Out[20]: 
       so_1   so_2   so_3
0       NaN    NaN    NaN
1       NaN    NaN    NaN
2       NaN    NaN    NaN
3       NaN    NaN    NaN
4     31.99  32.09  32.22
5       NaN    NaN    NaN
6       NaN    NaN    NaN
7       NaN    NaN    NaN
8       NaN    NaN    NaN
9     32.08  32.15  32.18
10  32.0871  32.11  32.17
11      NaN    NaN    NaN
```

Comment: Thanks @Andrew, I found a more practical way and explained below

Comment: Your solution makes sense, but I don't understand how it is more practical. Could you elaborate on that?

Comment: due to unknown reason, python does not replace '--' with nan so simply. I couldn't find why, but at least in case of netCDF files, the '--' values are masked values with which it is a disaster to work. So, using `df.mask()` works much better and indeed replaces those masked values which are not replaced using the normal replace command

Answer (score 0):

I found a more practical for my own question: using `df.mask` works awesome. pandas or numpy know '--' as a string and due to unknown reasons they replace not only them, but everything to nan. I found out that it is not a string like '--', but I have to introduce it is a masked value like `--` which is not a string. Then the following command would replace them with nan:

```
df_m=df.mask(df=='--', other=nan)
```

look here: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.mask.html